# Add a year If the second row month is smaller than First row month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following Query

```
declare @tempMonth table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Monthid int)
declare @tempDay table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Day int)

declare @AddedDate table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Datee date)

declare @StartEndDate table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,StartDate date,Enddate date)


insert into @tempMonth select words Months  from dbo.SplitString1('5|8|1|3','|')
insert into @tempDay select words Days  from dbo.SplitString1('10|11|12|13','|')

insert into @AddedDate 
select convert(varchar,(convert(varchar,Year)+'-'+convert(varchar,Month)+'-'+convert(varchar,Day))) Datee  from(
select td.ID,td.Day,tm.Monthid Month,  YEAR( getdate()) Year       --convert(date,convert(varchar,((Year(getdate()))+'-'+tm.Monthid+'-'+td.Day)))Datee
from @tempDay td
join @tempMonth tm on tm.ID=td.ID
) x


declare @t1 table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,StartDate date)
declare @t2 table(ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,StartDate date)


insert into @t1 select Datee StartDate from @AddedDate
insert into @t2 select Datee StartDate from @AddedDate

select t1.ID,t1.StartDate ,
case when t1.ID=4 then DATEADD(day,-1, (SELECT top 1 t3.StartDate FROM @t1 t3  ORDER BY t3.ID)) else 
DATEADD(day,-1,t2.StartDate) end EndDate from @t1 t1
left join @t2 t2 on t2.ID=t1.ID
```

This will produce the following table

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate
1   2015-05-10  2015-08-10
2   2015-08-11  2015-01-11
3   2015-01-12  2015-03-12
4   2015-03-13  2015-05-09
```

I want to increase the year If the second column **month** value is higher than 
first column value.

I have try to change the last select query like below

```
---
----
insert into @t1 select Datee StartDate from @AddedDate
insert into @t2 select Datee StartDate from @AddedDate

declare @Flag int=0;

select t1.ID,
case when @Flag=0 then t1.StartDate else DATEADD(year,1,t1.StartDate) end StartDate,

case when (month(t1.StartDate)>month(t2.StartDate)) then @Flag=1 end,

case when @Flag=0 then t2.StartDate else(DATEADD(YEAR,1,t2.StartDate)) end EndDate
from @t1 t1
left join @t2 t2 on t2.ID=t1.ID
```

But error occur, But I need the following output

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate
1   2015-05-10  2015-08-10
2   2015-08-11  2016-01-11
3   2016-01-12  2016-03-12
4   2016-03-13  2016-05-09
```

SplitString1 Function Definition is

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString1]( @StringValue varchar( 2000  
                                                     ) ,   
                                 @Delimiter char( 1  
                                                )  
                               )  
RETURNS @resulttable TABLE( words varchar( 2000  
                                         )  
                          )  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE  
       @index int;  
    DECLARE  
       @sliceOfStringValue varchar( 2000  
                                  );  

    SET @index = 1;  
    IF LEN( @StringValue  
          )  
       <   
       1  
    OR @StringValue IS NULL  
        BEGIN  
            RETURN  
        END;  

    WHILE @index != 0  
        BEGIN  
            SET @index = CHARINDEX( @Delimiter , @StringValue  
                                  );  
            IF @index != 0  
                BEGIN  
                    SET @sliceOfStringValue = LEFT( @StringValue , @index - 1  
                                                  );  
                END  
            ELSE  
                BEGIN  
                    SET @sliceOfStringValue = @StringValue;  
                END;  

            IF LEN( @sliceOfStringValue  
                  )  
               >   
               0  
                BEGIN  
                    INSERT INTO @resulttable( words  
                                            )  
                    VALUES( @sliceOfStringValue  
                          )  
                END;  

            SET @StringValue = RIGHT( @StringValue , LEN( @StringValue  
                                                        ) - @index  
                                    );  
            IF LEN( @StringValue  
                  )  
               =   
               0  
                BEGIN BREAK  
                END;  
        END;  
    RETURN;  
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about building on your query.  The following adds a year whenever the end date is *before* the start date:

```
with t as (
        select t1.ID, t1.StartDate ,
               (case when t1.ID=4 then DATEADD(day,-1, (SELECT top 1 t3.StartDate FROM @t1 t3  ORDER BY t3.ID))
                     else DATEADD(day,-1,t2.StartDate)
                end) as EndDate
        from @t1 t1 left join
             @t2 t2
             on t2.ID = t1.ID
       )
select id, StartDate,
       (case when EndDate < StartDate then dateadd(year, 1, EndDate)
             else EndDate
        end) as EndDate
from t;
```

If you only want to focus on the month:

```
select id, StartDate,
       (case when month(EndDate) < month(StartDate)
             then dateadd(year, 1, EndDate)
             else EndDate
        end) as EndDate
from t;
```

Comment: see the first row start date(2015-05-10) and second row start date(2015-08-11) the month is not greater (05>08) so you should not increase the end date year just minus one day. If once the month is greater after all the year should come 2016 (+1 year)

Comment: @MerbinJoe . . . It seems like a strange requirement, but that is why I included both options.

Comment: You may want to involve the year: `year(EndDate) * 100 + month(EndDate) < year(StartDate) * 100 + month(StartDate)`. That way, Dec 2014 will still be less than Jan 2015: 201412 < 201501.